# Yolov4 tiny weights convert to keras h5 file

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I have yolov4 tiny weights and cfg file, is there any way convert them to h5 file?

Answer (score 1):

To convert any weights from one format to another, you first need to load your model with your weights.

Convert the weights to floating point values. This means you need to read the weights for each layer of your model

Then save the weights to a format you desire using the specific library (in your case Keras).

You can refer to the below link on how to convert the weights to .h5

http://dsbyprateekg.blogspot.com/2020/06/how-to-convert-your-yolov4-weights-to.html?m=1