# YOLOv4 tiny weigths to keras h5

Tags: keras, deep-learning, yolo, darknet

his question has already been formulated here in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65564818/yolov4-tiny-weights-convert-to-keras-h5-file).

But there was only an answer, without help me a lot.

The problem is how to convert the YOLOv4 Tiny weights darknet to the keras h5 format?

Hope someone can help me.
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/david8862/keras-YOLOv3-model-set) GitHub repo to convert `darknet` weights for many Yolo variants to `.h5` format